# C - Using shared library

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, shared, libs

I have made makefile which is creating shared library of two C code files (I used gcc).
Makefile is also creating runnable main C file.
Now I need to know how to tell main C file to use my shared library - because I need to use functions which are already contained in code files in shared library.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this question about adding shared libraries to the linker, or about using functions from shared libraries in your code?

Comment: Is there special reason to make library? Why not simply include the source in each program?

Comment: About both of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `#include` the header file containing the declaration of the function(s) you want to use in your main file.
2. link with your shared library using `-L/path/to/libraries abc.c -l<yourLIb>`. [Assuming your libary name is `lib<yourLIb>.so`]

<sup>Note: You can find some good reads [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).</sup>

Comment: Everything is in the same folder, so do I use -L. "main fle name" -l<yourLIb> ???

Comment: @ondrousn yep. did you give it a try yet?

Answer (score 0):

Define function prototypes in header .h file(s). And add library name to linker parameters.